# Used a powershell script for Destiny 2 solo mode, exited it incorrectly. Can no longer matchmake

Tags: powershell

`if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File` "$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-1" -Direction Outbound -RemotePort 27000-27200,3097 -Protocol TCP -Action Block

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-2" -Direction Outbound -RemotePort 27000-27200,3097 -Protocol UDP -Action Block

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-3" -Direction Inbound -RemotePort 27000-27200,3097 -Protocol TCP -Action Block

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-4" -Direction Inbound -RemotePort 27000-27200,3097 -Protocol UDP -Action Block

Write-Host "Destiny 2 Solo mode activated. Press Enter to deactivate solo mode."

Read-Host

Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-1"

Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-2"

Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-3"

Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Destiny2-Solo-4"`

This was the script I guess, and basically what happened was I activated it and was running it. Then I exited the game without pressing enter to deactivate it (done many times). However, when I reopened the game, even after shutting down my computer I can no longer matchmake.

I'm not good with terminology with this stuff and I cant really find any help with this issue online. Does anyone have a solution to I guess unblock these "ports" or whatever they are? should I just reinstall the game? idk what to do.

Comment: Assuming these firewall rules are still applied and are responsible for your problem, try just running the script again and then hitting Enter. In general you should be wary of using elevated scripts without understanding what they do. In this case, it's fairly benign. It is setting up network rules to block traffic in and out of specific ports, which I presume are related to matchmaking. After you press Enter, it removes those rules. If you skip that bit, you'll end up with those ports blocked on your system.